# Is it possible to somehow use .setMicrosecondPosition() with line or is it only possible to do with clip

Tags: java, audio

I am currently making mp3 player in `NetBeans 12.1` and I can't find a way to control current position of a song.

I have tried using `.setMicrosecondPosition()`, but it seems it only works with the clip not with the line.
Is it even possible for my player to change current position of the track or should I change my code?

This is the code of the player.

```
public void run() {
        final File file = new File(filePath);
        try (final AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)) {
            final AudioFormat outFormat = getOutFormat(in.getFormat());
            final Info info = new Info(SourceDataLine.class, outFormat);

            try (final SourceDataLine line
                    = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info)) {
                getLine(line);
                line.getMicrosecondPosition();
                if (line != null) {
                    line.open(outFormat);
                    line.start();
  
                    long millis;
                    AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
                    Map<?, ?> properties = ((TAudioFileFormat) fileFormat).properties();
                    String key = "duration";
                    String title = "title";
                    Long microseconds = (Long) properties.get(key);
                    maksimumSekunde = (int)TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds(microseconds);
                    title1 = (String) properties.get(title);
                    int mili = (int) (microseconds / 1000);
                    sec = (mili / 1000) % 60;
                    min = (mili / 1000) / 60;

                    setVolumeDown(sliderGlasnoca.getValue());
                    //STREAM
                    int n = 0;
                    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    AudioInputStream inp = getAudioInputStream(outFormat, in);

                    while (n != -1) {
                        if (pauza == true) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (stop == true) {
                            synchronized (LOCK) {
                                LOCK.wait();
                            }

                        }
                        n = inp.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        if (n != -1) {
                            line.write(buffer, 0, n);
                        }
                        millis = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toMillis(line.getMicrosecondPosition());
                        trajanjeSekunde = (int)TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds(line.getMicrosecondPosition());
                        minutes = (millis / 1000) / 60;
                        seconds = ((millis / 1000) % 60);

                        //System.out.println(minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + "time = " + min + ":" + sec + " " + title1);
                    }
                    //STREAM
                    line.drain();
                    line.stop();
                    Finished();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException
                | LineUnavailableException
                | IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Its my first time posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always just counted and discarded frames from bytes being read via the `AudioInputStream`, but looking anew at the API, I see that one can use the `AudioInputStream.skip(...)` method to jump forward a given number of bytes. Calculating the number of bytes corresponding to a given amount of time involves knowing the number of bytes per frame, e.g., 16-bit encoding, stereo is 4 bytes per frame, and the sample rate.

IDK if one can reliably skip backwards. This will depend on whether one can "mark" and "reset" the file being read by the `AudioInputStream`. If these capabilities are supported, it seems conceivable that one could `mark(...)` the start of the `AudioInputStream`. Then, to go backwards, first `reset()` back to the beginning and then jump forward via `skip(...)`. I haven't tested this. A lot would depend on the number of bytes permitted in the `mark(...)` method.

If starting or stopping in the middle of playing audio, the data that is fed to the `SourceDataLine` would potentially exhibit "clicks" due to the discontinuity in the signal. To deal with that it might be necessary to convert the starts and stops to PCM and ramp the volume up if starting, or down if stopping. The number of frames required would probably need to be determined by experimenting. I'm guessing 64 frames for 44100fps might be a good first try.

Comment: Thank you :D, I totally forgot to check AudioInputStream to see what methods it offers. This gives me a lot of options to check out, but seems like my player cant mark() and reset(), specifically AudioInputStream returns false when markSupported() is checked.

Comment: Doesn't surprise me about "mark" and "reset". IDK what it takes to get that to work on an audio file. I've rarely seen it work with audio--but I stopped even bothering to test for it a long time ago.